# Strange ERROR: Could not find a version... during pip install

Tags: python, pip

Any idea about this strange error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycrypto==2.6.1 (from versions: 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycrypto==2.6.1
```

It is strange because I've never seen a situation like this in which the unfounded version, is being included between available versions.

As you can see `2.6.1` is at the end of `from versions`.

Do you have any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

PyCrypto is only supported up to Python 3.3 as last version [dates back to 2013](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/), please consider install [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) instead which works as a replacement for PyCrypto.

Comment: thank you for your answer, while you are right, it can't be my answer. because this issue happened today and there is not much change during these days in our codebase. changing to PyCryptodome definitely is a good suggestion.